# C# Selenium - Chrome Browser Print Modal

Tags: c#, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Using C# Selenium for E2E tests.

I need to assert that the Chrome print/print preview is rendering either by checking the URL is correct OR that the Print button is present.

Once that's done, I'll need to close down the modal and return to the original page.

I've tried:

`driver.switchTo().frame(0);` and various numbers - "Cannot find frame" is the usual response.

`driver.switchTo().frame("id of the element");` - same response.

I'd rather not have to go down the image comparison route.

The same test using JS/Protractor/Selenium, this line worked but I cannot seem to replicate this in C#.

`browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){ browser.switchTo().window(handles[1])`

Any ideas please?

Thanks

[image]